# Electron App: How to authorize domain on Firebase

Tags: firebase, oauth, electron

In my electron app, I have integrated the **firebase google sign-in authentication method**. This method is working properly in the local environment. But after packaging the application (for Linux environment), I am getting an error '**Error while login into Gmail account FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/unauthorized-domain)**'. When I tried to find the cause of this error, I found that we have to add the respective domain to the authorization tab but the firebase app domain is already added in settings. As you can see in the screenshot [image]

**What else do I need to add here in the domain setting?**

Comment: please share here how you solved this issue, since still this problem is not resovled.